# Default css class for sorting column in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii, datagridview, yii2, dataprovider

I just want to add default class for sorted column.

I have code that add class attribute with value 'ASC' or 'DESC' when I sorted table by that column (part of code):

```
GridView::widget(
    [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'id', // <---- sorted by default, have 'class="desc"'
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 120px'],
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'name', //<- want to append 'class="sortable"'
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: left'],
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: left'],
            ],
...
        ]
    ]
);
```

What i need - add 'class="sortable"' for generated

```
<a href="/my/action">Name</a>
```

links in the thead

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you could add (this property to each column that should have extra class or other properties like style)

```
'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'sortable'],
```

but this add class to the th element then you could use it in CSS like this

```
th.sortable > a
```

Comment: there is no property with the name of `headerOptions` in `GridView`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I belive it's is look at: renderHeaderCell in yiisofl\yii2\grid\Column.php 

return Html::tag('th', $this->renderHeaderCellContent(), $this->headerOptions);

also it's not the property of Grid component as is byt the grid columns array 

GridView::widget([
....
'columns' => [
......
[
  .......
  'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:140px;'],
]

Comment: yes , you are right here, i just wanted to take back my down vote ,but unable intill you edit  can you please mention it in the answer as it looked that you are talking about the grid view. thanks for clearification

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam edited ( I think that should be clear to all now :) )

Comment: done, thanks apart frm all this its recommended and easier to use css to change the icons , just saying, all the best

Answer (score 0):

The sort icon `class` is set within the default `site.css` file that is loaded by `AppAsset.php` in your 
`application/views/layouts/main.php` or if you have some other name for the `layout` file, you have to adjust the `css` class `a.asc:after` and `a.desc:after` if you need to update the icon for the sort.

```
a.asc:after {
    content: "\e155";
}

a.desc:after {
    content: "\e156";
}
```

Similarly, there are `numerical` and `ordinal` sort classes too if you need to change them too depending on the requirements.

```
.sort-numerical a.asc:after {
    content: "\e153";
}

.sort-numerical a.desc:after {
    content: "\e154";
}

.sort-ordinal a.asc:after {
    content: "\e155";
}

.sort-ordinal a.desc:after {
    content: "\e156";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [
>         'attribute' => 'title',
>         'sortLinkOptions' => [
>               'class' => 'sortable'
>           ],
>       ]

```
this option can be used to add custom class on
```

> th > a

[check actual implmented code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaJ5K.png)